# How can we show the convergence of $x_n = \sin(2\pi (n^3-n^2+1)^{\frac{1}{3}})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Show that the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ defined by $$x_n = \sin(2\pi (n^3-n^2+1)^{\frac{1}{3}})$$ converges and compute its limit.

Comment: You need to find a good approximation for that cube root, as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 7):

We have
$$
2\pi\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2+1}=2\pi n\sqrt[3]{1-1/n+1/n^3}.
$$

Now use $(1+u)^\alpha=1+\alpha u+O(u^2)$ as $u$ approaches $0$, to get:
$$
2\pi n\sqrt[3]{1-1/n+1/n^3}=2\pi n\left(1-\frac{1}{3n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)=2\pi n-\frac{2\pi}{3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)
$$

Then 
$$
x_n=\sin\left(2\pi n-\frac{2\pi}{3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)=\sin\left(-\frac{2\pi}{3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \right)
$$
so the limit is
$$
\sin(-2\pi/3)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}.
$$

Comment: You are assuming, of course, that $n$ sweeps through the integers.  I think you are right, but the OP needs to acknowledge it as true.

Comment: @rlgordonma : $x_n$ is a sequence, $n$ definitively sweeps through the integers.

Comment: @rlgordonma I don't understand your comment, sorry. The OP considers a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$. So most likely $n$ is a nonnegative integer, no?

Comment: @julien: yes, of course!  My mistake. +1

Comment: I don't see the $3/2$ --- should be $1/3$, right?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, definitely. I make all sorts of silly mistakes since yesterday...Hopefully this is correct now. Thank you!

Comment: @julien: (+1) for your answer.

Comment: @Chris'ssister Thank you! I would bet that the OP will accept your answer rather than mine. We'll see.

Comment: I only post questions/answers for the love to math. The points mean nothing to me. (they might be worthy for my sister)

Comment: @Chris'ssister I was actually not thinking about points when I made my comment. Rather, I was thinking that if the OP asked this question, most likely he/she does not know Taylor expansions and therefore a good old l'Hospital's rule answer is certainly more appropriate. To tell you the truth, I don't really care about points either.

Answer (score 4):

It smells like an easy high school question
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi (\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2+1}-n)+2\pi n)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(2\pi (\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2+1}-n))=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
because
$$\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x^3-x+1}-1}{x}=\lim_{x\to0} \frac{3x^2-1}{3(x^3-x+1)^{2/3}}=-\frac{1}{3}$$
by the cute  l'Hôpital's rule, and then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2+1}-n)=-\frac{1}{3}$$ 
$$\sin \left(-\frac{2\pi}{3}\right)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Chris.

Comment: No need for Taylor.

Comment: Your third equality probably needs some explanations.

Comment: @julien: is it better now?

Comment: Way better, thanks. And +1.

Comment: @julien: thanks!

Comment: @julien: there is a nice generalization posted on MSE of the limit where I applied l'Hospital's rule, but I can't find it now (and too lazy to type it above). Actually, at first I only looked at the coefficient of the $2$nd term under the radical and then at the order of the radical, and then I knew the limit. ($\lim_{n\to\infty} (\sqrt[3]{n^3-n^2+1}-n)=-\frac{1}{3}$)

Comment: I think you made substitution $n$ by $\frac{1}{x}$ in you 3rd step. I love your approach. Thank you for your valuable time.

Comment: @ftolessa: you're welcome! :-)